# Static block only call in few category not on all category

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

i made one static block, i want to display that block in all category but its only display on *subcategory* of *furniture* and another category which is created by me. but it is not call on *electronic* and *apparel* category.
   I copied `catalog.xm`l into *example_theme/layout* and it is as below

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/> 
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">

            <block type="cms/block" name="example_block" >
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>example-block</block_id></action>//this is block which i call
            </block>
         <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>

    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

so, how can i get solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you if any of you try to read my Question..

i got its answer thats why i post here.

Just need to put below code

```
<block type="cms/block" name="example_block" >
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>example-block</block_id></action>//this is block which i call
</block>
```

in catalog.xml labeled with

```
<label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    <catalog_category_default translate="label">
       <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
```

This handle only applies to categories that are not anchors. The categories you mentioned are most likely set to not be anchors. To apply this change to categories that are anchors you need to apply your changes inside this handle.

```
    <catalog_category_layered>
```

Comment: Thank You!!! i got it's answer by myself also. by the way thank you its true answer

Comment: can u help me to know what is this layered category?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work